# Struct contains a function and object to be handled by the function in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I am trying to create a struct that contains a function and an object to be handled by that function. For example:

```
public delegate void MyFunc(object o);

public struct MyData
{
    public object o;
    public MyFunc func;

    public MyData(object o, MyFunc func)
    {
        this.o = o;
        this.func = func;
    }

    public HandleData()
    {
        func(o);
    }
}
```

The purpose of this struct is to use any function to handle any data.

I wrap this struct into a IntPtr data type and send to another to handle this struct

```
private void PrepareData(object o, MyFunc func)
{
    MyData md = new MyData(o, func);
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(md);
    IntPtr wParam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(md, wParam, false);
    DoJob(wParam);
}

private void DoJob(IntPtr wParam)
{
    if (wParam != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Type type = typeof(MyData);
        MyData md = (MyData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p,type);
        md.HandleData();
    }
}
```

Sometimes, I receive error like:

1) "[System.RuntimeType] = {Name = Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized. FullName = Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.}"

2) in HanldeData function, the func instance variable has been Garbage Collected, and is not able to work properly.
like:

{Method = Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is optimized.}

Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' has detected a problem

Note: I haven't check the "optimise code" in the property of the project.

[image]

Comment: Do you get an exception or something? Your code runs fine here.

Comment: "the func instance is already garbage collected" err... no. Nothing that still has a reference existing is garbage collected.

Comment: Don't make mutable structs.

Comment: **What do the errors say**? Unless you're using P/Invoke, you do not have GC issues.

Comment: @Slaks: what do you mean by "mutable structs"? I got some error warnings: like "[System.RuntimeType] = {Name = Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized. FullName = Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.}"

Comment: So you can't debug it... So?

Comment: Those aren't errors; that's just the debugger unable to show some values.  What exception do you get?

Comment: My story is actually not simple like that. Let me update my post.

Comment: I did update my post. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: What happends if you uncheck the "optimize code" checkbox?

Comment: I haven't checked optimize code checkbox.

Comment: @chipbk10: Please confirm this is used in P/Invoke, else this whole question is nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

Without a complete code example and a clear description of what you are actually trying to achieve here, it's impossible to know for sure what the best answer. That said, frankly, the whole scheme seems nuts to me. `IntPtr`? Seriously?

I don't see anything in your question that describes a problem that can't be accomplished *more easily* simply by wrapping the delegate and object in a new delegate object.

E.g.:

```
private void PrepareData(object o, MyFunc func)
{
    DoJob(() => func(o));
}

private void DoJob(Action wParam)
{
    if (wParam != null)
    {
        wParam();
    }
}
```

Note that in your original code, if the only references left to your object and delegate are in the unmanaged block you allocate, they *may* in fact be GC'ed, as they would then be unreachable via any managed reference (which is the only thing the GC cares about).

Note also that even if the objects are still reachable via a managed reference, that the GC may *move* the objects in memory (e.g. to compact the heap), rendering the values you've copied into your unmanaged block of memory useless.

If you stick to the use of *managed code and objects* in your program, you will avoid these problems.

(I also note that your code example doesn't even seem valid, as your `DoJob()` parameter name is `wParam`, but the variable you check and marshal back to a managed struct is named `p`).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, my code is very complicated. I tried to write it in the simple way to give a clear explanation. Sorry for misleading with the different name p. I need to use IntPtr, because the function which receives the structure (private DoJob(IntPtr ...)) in the format of IntPtr. I cannot change it, because it comes from third party library. Therefore, I cannot use Action here.

Comment: Then you need to pin both the delegate and the object instances before copying them to unmanaged memory. If the third-party library is unmanaged code, then it's obviously not unpacking the values the way you indicated and the delegate reference may be unusable anyway. It's possible in that case, you should be using p/invoke to call the method. If the third-party library is _managed_ code, then you should find another library; if someone publishing a managed assembly came up with this scheme for this part, there's no telling what other awful code is in there.

Comment: @chipbk10: I agree with Peter. Also, you should be using HandleRef, and not IntPtr. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.handleref This way you dont even have to bother with a struct.

Comment: As said, I use a third party library, the DoJob comes from that library uses IntPtr as its parameter. I cannot use HanldeRef.

Comment: I find that using the GC.KeepAlive() has the same purpose, and it works for me. So, I think in this case, HandleRef or GC.KeepAlive() are the same.

Comment: @chipbk10: `GC.KeepAlive()` does not ensure that your objects won't be moved in memory. You need to pin the object.

Comment: How to pin the object, Peter?

Comment: Call `GCHandle.Alloc()` with `GCHandleType.Pinned`. That said, I reiterate: if this is an unmanaged library you are trying to interact with, you will be better off using the existing p/invoke mechanisms instead of reimplementing them yourself (e.g. using `GCHandle`). If this is a managed library, you should find a completely different library, because a managed library that makes you jump through these hoops is lousy code, and can't be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the Unmanaged Code will be GC'ed. However, I follow the tutorial: [link](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/passing-structures-between-managed-and-unmanaged-code/)

and what I am missing in my code is just to forget free the allocated memory for the next use.

```
private void DoJob(IntPtr wParam)
{
    if (wParam != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Type type = typeof(MyData);
        MyData md = (MyData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p,type);
        md.HandleData();

        // Free the unmanaged representation of MyData struct.
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(wParam);
    }
}
```

It works very well until now after many tests.

Comment: Why is the caller of `DoJob` not cleaning up. If you did not create it, you dont clean it up. Simple.

Comment: Because the PrepareData in my code is a function which is called (sometimes) from a thread. DoJob always occurs in the main thread. I am not sure, the cleanup should be in PrepareData or in DoJob? Thanks for your reminder.

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. You wrote earlier that "I use a third party library, the DoJob comes from that library". Yet, your answer here shows you _modifying_ that `DoJob()` method, the one you previously indicated you had no control over. If you can modify this method, fix it so that it's strictly managed code. If you can't, why is the above an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, the function comes from the framework I am using, not from a third party library. And the function uses IntPtr as its parameter, and I can control and modify the code in that function. Yes, it is a managed code.

Comment: If it's managed code, then you need to just not do it this way. Just pass a normal `Action` delegate, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: The DoJob function receives the IntPtr as its parameter, not Action delegate.

Comment: You wrote that you own the `DoJob()` method. So change the parameter type.

Comment: No, the DoJob looks like an event handler (e.g., Button_OnClick(object sender, ...)). It is equipped by the framework I bought. I cannot change its parameter. I must use this method, not write it on my own way.